# Font Awesome Icon Cannot Be Exported With D3JS Graph Using Filesaver.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, font-awesome, filesaver.js, d3-force-directed

I was using `D3JS` to create a force directed graph and I replaced the nodes with font awesome icon. Everything works fine until when I tried to convert it to blob and download it using `filesaver.js`.

This is the code that I used to create force directed graph:
https://bl.ocks.org/heybignick/3faf257bbbbc7743bb72310d03b86ee8

This is the code that I used to convert my SVG graph to blob:
http://bl.ocks.org/Rokotyan/0556f8facbaf344507cdc45dc3622177

This is the part of the code that I replace the circle nodes with font awesome icon:

```
node.append('text')
    .attr("class", "nodeText")
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
    .attr('font-family', 'Font Awesome\\ 5 Free')
    .style("stroke", "green")
    .text('\uf007');
```

I expect the image output will be the same as the force directed graph above but with the font awesome icon instead of the circle nodes.

Answer (score 0):

After some times, I finally realize that I need to convert the Font Awesome icon to svg path instead of putting it as the `<i class="fas fa-user" />` or with the text `'\uf007'`.